# Auth0 Angular SDK for SPA: How Refresh Access Token Work?

Tags: angular, auth0

I read about this [post](https://community.auth0.com/t/auth0-auth0-spa-js-access-token-refresh/28048) from Auth0 Community. It mentions the [Refresh Token Rotation](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/refresh-tokens/refresh-token-rotation?_ga=2.155397951.500124087.1614886375-247905816.1614446881). Which is the process of exchanging a Refresh Token to get a new Access Token and a new Refresh Token, invalidating the old Refresh Token.

This process is available in the Angular SDK for SPA: [auth0-angular](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-angular). As mention in the solution.

However, when I read the document: [Auth0 Angular SDK for Single Page Apps](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0-angular-spa) there is no guide on how to refresh the token to get new access and refresh token.

Therefore I presume, that with the usage of the `AuthHttpInterceptor` see this [doc](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0-angular-spa#import-the-http-interceptor). *It will work under the hood?*

Does this interceptor provide the process to check if the access token is invalid and then silently get a new access token? Or Do we still have to manually implement this feature in our angular frontend application?

Please enlighten.